# Problems with bubbling event on dragleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

I have a working example with `dragenter` and `dragleave` events that highlight an area where the file should be dropped. This example [works correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/kURAh/).

Right now if I just add a single `<span>` inside of my dragenter region, [highlighting does not work correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/kURAh/2/) anymore (when you hover the image on top of the text - highlighting disappears). As you see `dragleave` is called multiple times.

All I changed is substituted `Drop files here` to `<span>Drop files here</span>`

Also there is knockout code there, but I believe that it has nothing to do with the bug. I understand that the problem is with event bubbling, but

```
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
```

does not help. Any idea how to make it work with dom elements indside?

**P.S.** this is just a simplified example and it looks like I was not able to properly make it (I was thinking that the only way to solve it through JS, and it appears that the way I described it it is possible to solve it with css as well). Sorry for this confusion. Example looks more like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kURAh/8/). Not only the Text is inside of the dropable element, but when you drop something, elements appears there. These elements are clickable.

The problem with Malk's solution is that `:after` element stays on top of these clickable elements and thus making them unclickable.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can attach the handlers to an overlay div that is positioned after and on-top-of the span:

```
<div class="col-md-12" data-bind="foreach: dropZones">
    <div class="drop_zone">
        <span>Drop files here</span>
        <div class="drop_zone_overlay" data-bind="event:{
                dragover:   function(data, e){ $root.dragover(e);},
                drop:       function(data, e){ $root.drop(e, $data);},
                dragenter:  function(data, e){ $root.dragenter(e, $index());},
                dragleave:  function(data, e){ $root.dragleave(e, $index());}
            }">
          </div>
    </div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: elements" style="height: 100px">
        <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.drop_zone {
    border: 2px dashed #bbb;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font: 20pt bold'Vollkorn';
    color: #bbb;

    position:relative;
}

.drop_zone_overlay { 
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rWWK5/

---

EDIT

Actually you do not need to add another element at all. You can create a pseudo-element with CSS `:after` that should work to cover the content.

```
.drop_zone {
    ...
    position:relative;
}
.drop_zone:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ewng9/

---

EDIT 2

You can use this technique to cover the contents only when dragging. You just need to change your `.css({})` call to `toggleClass()` and put the `:after` on the new class.

http://jsfiddle.net/dKsmw/

This will also lets you create an overlay that tints the background elements:

```
.drop_zone_hover:after{
    ...
    background-color:#0f0;
    opacity:0.6;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The problem is that I am showing a simplified example and there is much more than `<span>` inside. This span also is visible based on whether there elements inside of the dropzone. For this reason I can not move that pesky `<span>` outside of the dropzone. Still thank you for looking into the problem and take my +1.

Comment: The span is still in the dropzone. I simply added another div next to it.

Comment: I am really sorry, but it still does not work for me. I updated my answer with more adequate example. Will appreciate if you will be able to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Malk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23945013/1593273) is valid.  Using an overlay or mask to sit above the drop zone and it's children when you drag over and drop.  This prevents the issue you were experiencing with the `span`

I've created a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kURAh/10/) with your newest example.

Comment: Thank you. Even this does not help. In your example it works really nice, but when I try to port it to my code (which is a css mess) it does not work. I found a workaround to color the element also on dragover. I understand that this is inefficient, but I will leave this till I will be able to spend more time.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this question and associated answers looking for a solution to this myself. I didn't like any of the solutions. They all involve adding additional elements to the DOM to mask the composite elements of the drag target. They feel like hacks trying to avoid the actual problem: correctly handling the event bubbling behavior. My solution does exactly that and as a result is much cleaner and simpler.

The solution is to simply check if the node that is receiving the drag upon a dragleave event is still contained within the node that you want to be the drop target. E.g.

```
<div class="dropTarget">
  <span>Composite Element 1</span>
  <span>Composite Element 2</span>
<div>
```

```
const dropTarget = document.querySelector('.dropTarget');

dropTarget.addEventListener('dragleave', (event) => {
  if (dropTarget.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
    // We are still dragging within the dropTarget parent element
    return;
  }
  // We have left the dropTarget parent element
  // Do whatever you want to do in response to 'dragleave'
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Works exactly as expected! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. And, as with most problems, they can be solved with javascript.

Like OP, I also don't want to have an element cover the entire dropzone and render clickable elements inert.

Essentially, just make sure the mouse position is inside the container's bounding box.

In the `dragleave` event handler, get the `currentTarget`'s bounding box with `getBoundingClientRect`.

The drag event will have the `clientX` and `clientY` properties which represent the mouse location.

Check that the mouse position falls within the `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` edges of the dropzone.  If it is within the bounding box, then return early and don't handle the `dragleave` event any further.

```js
const handleDragLeave = e => {
  if (isInsideContainer(e)) return
  e.currentTarget.classList.remove("dragged-over")
}

const isInsideContainer = e => {
  const { top, bottom, left, right } = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect()
  return e.clientX < right && e.clientX > left && e.clientY > top && e.clientY < bottom
}

const dropzone = document.querySelector(".dropzone")

dropzone.addEventListener("dragenter", e => {
  e.currentTarget.classList.add("dragged-over")
})

dropzone.addEventListener("dragleave", handleDragLeave)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.dropzone {
  border: 2px dashed black;
  padding: 3rem;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.dragged-over {
  border-color: limegreen;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropzone">
  <span>Drag and drop here</span>
</div>
```